# Want to change the background color selected item(clicked item) in Android ListView by layout XML

Tags: android, listview, background

I want to change the background color of clicked ListView Item in my Android app(Dont want to use ClickOnListener implementation).I am adding my Layout.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minHeight="48dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
   >

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_item"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/homeButtonTextSize"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
     ></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I used  some selectors.But not able to produce required output.Also try with "android:activatedBackgroundIndicator" .But doesnt works. Please Help me

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`android:listSelector`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:listSelector) attribute on your ListView and point to a `<selector>` drawable. Also, you should not use an OnCLickListener for each row, use an [`OnItemClickListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) instead (with [`ListView.setOnItemClickListener()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener))

Comment: Yes ,I am using OnItemClickListener().   That is not  issue.I tried with "android:listSelector" .It doent works.

Comment: Then there is probably something wrong with the drawable, because the `listSelector` attribute most certainly works.

Comment: I added  a line-"android:listSelector="@drawable/background_color" in the TextView of given  xml. Also added "<drawable name="background_color">#FF0000</drawable>"  in color.xml.              But no use. have any suggestion?

Comment: I amusing android version 4.3

Comment: You are not using a `<selector>` drawable. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#selector-element